# C# array won't work

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a piece of code to create an array of 100 elements which will randomize based on the numbers from a set array. However whenever I enter "y" I am looking the array to delete the last element and add a new random element to the start and move everything in between one to the right to allow for this. However at the moment it is completely changing the array every time I enter "y". Can anyone help with this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

            int Min = values[0];
            int Max = values[5] + 1;
            int w = 0 ; 
            int[] rndValues = new int[100]; 

            Random rndNum = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Random001 " +  w);
            for (int i = 0; i < rndValues.Length; i++)
            {
                rndValues[i] = rndNum.Next(Min, Max);
            }

                Console.WriteLine("Random  " +  w);
            foreach(var item in rndValues)
            {
               Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
            }

if (w==0)

{
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            prob(rndValues, Min, Max,w);

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    w++;
}           

if (w>0)
{
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("To change elements in the array press y");

                // read input
                var s = Console.ReadLine();

                if(s == "y")
                {
                    //rndValues[99] = 0;

                    for(int i = 0; i == rndValues.Length; i++)
                    {

                        if (i != rndValues.Length)
                        {
                            rndValues[rndValues.Length-i] = rndValues[(rndValues.Length-i)-1];
                        }
                        else if (i == rndValues.Length)
                        {
                            rndValues[0] = rndNum.Next(Min, Max);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }

                prob(rndValues, Min, Max,w);
            }
}


        }

        public static void prob(int[] rndValues, int Min, int Max, int w )
        {

            double[] count = new double[rndValues.Length];

            //Loop through min to max and count the occurances
            for (int i = Min; i <Max; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rndValues.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (rndValues[j] == i)
                    {
                        count[i] = count[i] + 1;

                    }                   
                }
            }

            //For displaying output only            
                        foreach(var item in rndValues)
            {
               Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("W " +  w);
            for (int i = Min; i < Max; i++)
            {
                count[i] = (count[i] / rndValues.Length) * 100;

                Console.WriteLine("Probability of the number " + i + " is " + count[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ` for(int i = 0; i == rndValues.Length; i++)` - well, that looks very suspicious... that'll not loop at all, surely? except for zero-length arrays, which will loop once despite being empty (and thus: fail);   `if (i != rndValues.Length)` and that'll always be true (arrays are zero-based); I'm very confused what you're trying to do here...

Comment: From the description you might want to use a `Queue` instead of an array.

Comment: Wouldn't `rndValues[rndValues.Length-i]` be out of bounds for `i=0`? The loop is suspicious anyway, and indeed, this doesn't seem to be a good use case for an array. Even a List would be better.

Comment: do yo mean to use Array.Resize(ref T, 11)

Comment: So many problems with the last for loop in main, you might as well delete it, take a 30 minute break and just rewrite it.

Comment: It compiles without errors, but it keeps changing the array completely instead of just the first and last numbers

Comment: @StewartHouston CompilingCode != FunctionalCode. You have to debug to see at which lines there is an functional error. Read the hints here in the comments and you should be able to fix a lot.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] next time, with emphasis on **minimal**

Comment: If you're deleting the last element, and adding at the front, then a List<int> would be a better choice.